NVD Error: Invalid API key since NIST CVSS v4.0 changes
I have a process that uses the NVD API to pull down vulnerability data. It has worked fine for years.
Suddenly, I get periodic errors in the log, e.g. :
Downloaded 6000 CVEs.
Process finished at 2024-07-02 11:02:55
Total duration: 173.34 seconds
Downloaded 8000 CVEs.
Error: Invalid API key
Process finished at 2024-07-02 15:01:10
Total duration: 0.30 seconds
Downloaded 0 CVEs.
Process finished at 2024-07-02 17:00:37
Total duration: 1.92 seconds
Downloaded 0 CVEs.
Error: Invalid API key

I tested the issue with this code here:
import requests
import logging
import time

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='/<dir>/api_key_check.log', level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s')

def is_valid_api_key(apiKey, retries=3, delay=5, timeout=10):
    test_url = 'https://services.nvd.nist.gov/rest/json/cves/2.0'
    test_params = {'startIndex': 0, 'resultsPerPage': 1}
    headers = {'apiKey': apiKey}

    for attempt in range(retries):
        try:
            logging.info(f"Attempt {attempt + 1} to check API key.")
            test_response = requests.get(test_url, params=test_params, headers=headers, timeout=timeout)
            if test_response.status_code == 200:
                logging.info("API key is valid.")
                return True
            elif test_response.status_code == 403:
                logging.error("Forbidden: The API key might be invalid or rate-limited.")
                return False
            else:
                logging.error(f"Unexpected status code {test_response.status_code} on attempt {attempt + 1}")
        except requests.Timeout:
            logging.error(f"Request timed out on attempt {attempt + 1}")
        except requests.RequestException as e:
            logging.error(f"Request failed on attempt {attempt + 1}: {e}")
        time.sleep(delay)

    logging.error("API key validation failed after multiple attempts.")
    return False

# Replace 'your_api_key_here' with your actual API key
apiKey = 'your_api_key_here'
if is_valid_api_key(apiKey):
    print("API key is valid.")
else:
    print("Error: Invalid API key.")

I run that and I get:
Error: Invalid API key.

NIST and the NVD people are not great at responding. This has been broken for 4 days.
They have this on their chat group:
https://groups.google.com/a/list.nist.gov/g/nvd-news
Has anyone experienced this issue, or have any guidance?

I don't have an API key to try it out, but their API documentation includes:

Immediately after activation, API keys can be included as a parameter of the requestor’s URL string

I don't see anything in the documentation that suggests you can provide it as a header and I think it's likely that it has never worked as a header but the API has previously not required a key to work and you are just encountering their new lower rate limits.

I managed to check my api key using "curl -H "apiKey: 12345XYZ" "https://services.nvd.nist.gov/rest/json/cves/2.0?startIndex=0&resultsPerPage=1" and it is valid. The code for the download itself has been flawless for years until 30th June 2024. Regarding rate limits, I see "the rate limit with an API key is 50 requests in a rolling 30 second window." on their site but I am not sure this is "new" and could therefore be the cause. It'd be great if they dated their comments and updates :-(

Same problem with our old apikey we recreated one and it works....

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Was your API Key working, intermittently, so, pulling down data one minute and then showing a failure the next and then, fine again, in a circle? I would get a new one but this one works. The API Error message seems to be a catch-all for issues on the other end, with the NVD infrastructure / network.
